# Java - Best way to download a webpage's source html

Tags: java, download

I'm writing a little crawler. What is the best way to download a web page's source html? I'm currently using little piece of code below but some times the result is just half of the page's source!!! I don't know what's the problem. Some people suggested that I should use Jsoup but using .get.html() function from Jsoup also returns half of the page's source if it's too long. Since I'm writing a crawler, it's very important that the method support unicode (UTF-8) and the efficiency is also very important. I wanted to know the best modern way to do it so I asked you guys since I'm new to Java. Thanks.

Code:

```
public static String downloadPage(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            URL pageURL = new URL(url);
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(pageURL.openStream(), "utf-8");
            try {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                    text.append(scanner.nextLine() + NL);
                }
            }
            finally{
                scanner.close();
            }
            return text.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'm very pleased with the Apache HTTP library http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/.  If you're writing a web crawler, which I am also, you may greatly appreciate the control it gives over things like cookies and client sharing and the like.

Comment: It's not a rich crawler but I want it to do what it does as fast and perfect as possible. For the moment I just want it to download the page's source and I don't need that much of control but if it doesn't introduce so much complexity to my code, I'd be more than happy to use it. What do you think?

Comment: Now that I found out what the problem was, do you think I should go with this library or I should use my old code?

Comment: Both solutions work but there were some problems with the first one (for example imdb.com would return a 403 error). So I chose this one as answer. It's very easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

I use [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) `String html = IOUtils.toString(url.openStream(), "utf-8");`

Comment: Again the same problem. The returned string ends with `...` and it's length is: 439802

Comment: @Alireza Noori give me the target url

Comment: `Utilities.downloadPage("http://www.stackoverflow.com").length()` has returned : `191760` and it's last characters are: `<div class="votes">
...`

Comment: OK. Problem solved!!!! Eclipse was showing just half of my String hence this problem!! I wrote this output to a file and everything was fine! I couldn't find any way that I could check the full String at the debug time!! Awesome! Seriously! The more I spend time with Java, the more I love .Net!!!